# MIN() not returning min value on another column

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables topics and posts, the engine is InnoDB, and there are many posts with one topic_id, and I have a simple query like this:

```
select post_id, MIN(post_time) AS post_time from test1_posts where topic_id=19;
```

I would expect it to return the post_id which has the minimum post_time, and in most cases, it does.

My question is, under what circumstances, it will NOT return the post_id which has the minimum post_time?

Comment: Without GROUP BY, there is a single group and it is nondeterministic which post_id value to choose for the group. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that it will always return `post_id` corresponding to minimum `post_time`, because MySQL stores data as an unordered data-set; and `post_id` is not being processed under any aggregation function.

Only time when you can be 100% sure is that you have only one post for the given `topic_id`

You should rather order your data based on `post_time` in ascending order and use `LIMIT 1` to find the row corresponding to minimum post_time. Check the following:

```
SELECT post_id, post_time 
FROM test1_posts 
WHERE topic_id = 19 
ORDER BY post_time ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm curious about the "no guarantee" part. I have tried to change the post_id, and post_time manually into different order. That sql actually always return the post_id with the minimum post_time, but I do have one case that is returning a wrong post_id. I don't understand why, they are using the same table, same code.

Comment: @mok what is the case ? A lot depends on the server also. As I said, it is an unordered dataset, so all eventually depends on how MySQL decided to store them. Mostly it will store in the order they were inserted in DB. But sometimes there may be intermediate update/inserts which can cause the order to change

Comment: I don't know what case, that's the problem. I can't recreate it anywhere else. The table, data, mysql settings looks all the same. I guess I have to  just use the right syntax and forget about it.

Comment: @mok yes better to use deterministic way so that you are always sure. If this answer helped you, do consider upvoting it and marking as accepted answer (green tick). Thanks :)